# How to return multiple layers from pointToLayer leaflet geojson

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I want to add a marker icon and a boundary box to the map from a single data item. This is because I need to show both the location and rough size of a work site.

I can add a maker like this

```
pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng)
{
    return L.marker(latlng);
}
```

And I can add a rectangle like this

```
pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng)
{
    return L.rectangle(feature.properties.rect);
}
```

How can I add both at once?

[image: Example of how map should look]

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use a layer group. `pointToLayer` expects a return type of `ILayer`.

```
pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng)
{
    let oMyMarker = L.marker(latlng);
    let oMyRect = L.rectangle(feature.properties.rect);
    return L.layerGroup([oMyMarker, oMyRect]);
}
```

However I found that sometimes this was causing Leaflet to throw exceptions because it was trying to use `getLatLng()` and `setLatLng(latlng)` on the returned layer group.

I found this hack works around that exception, for my purposes I never update existing layers therfore I do not care if `setLatLng(latlng)` does anything or not.

```
pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng)
{
    let oMyMarker = L.marker(latlng);
    let oMyRect = L.rectangle(feature.properties.rect);
    let oLayer = L.layerGroup([oMyMarker, oMyRect]);
    if (typeof oLayer.getLatLng === 'undefined')
    {
        if (typeof oLayer._latlng === 'undefined') oLayer._latlng = latlng;
        oLayer.getLatLng = function () { return this._latlng; };
        if (typeof oLayer.setLatLng === 'undefined')
        {
            oLayer.setLatLng = function (val_latlng) { this._latlng = val_latlng; return; };
        }
    }
    return oLayer;
}
```

If you need methods `getLatLng()` and `setLatLng(latlng)` to work correctly on the layer group I suggest you make the methods we add there do a loop over the collection of child layers it contains to call the methods on all of them.